Record in playwright in existing devtools session using codegen
I have playwright installed with Python.
I have an application for which I can open remote debugging. Using chromium.connect_over_cdp(websocket_url), I am able to connect to same and work.
But I need record option for the same i.e playwright codegen.
How to achieve this for this case?
